# Web App script fails to launch by other users

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

My question is not about Docs only, but about Drive. I developed a web app, published for executing by users accessing the app, with access for everyone. and when I follow the given link by myself, I see pop-up for granting the access to my app. And after it my script starts for me.

But if I try to choose another account (for testing purposes) when the app asks me for granting access, I do the same, there appears "Authorization successful" for a moment, pop-up closes, but immediately appears again, and asks for permissions, and so on again and again like in a loop. When I check account settings I see that the app has access, but it doesn't start.

Remarkably, that while developing, I tried to launch it many times by different accounts and it worked fine then.

When I use incognito tab, it asks me to login, and having it done, I succeed to start the app. But when I try to start with usual browser tab a pop-up is appears and asks to review permissions. Clicking "review permission" it asks me to login offering my default account (which I use to develop and which launching process is ok), and choose another.

Comment: In usual browser tab if multiple google accounts are logged in then you shall get the error. Try logging out from all the accounts and sign in with a single account and run the code. Also, if you can share the code here we can try to look if it has an error.

Comment: Yes, we can use incognito, but it's not handily. Here is the code please: https://script.google.com/d/1rE4CTSUzoie_k9gSTK-YYfKpN1XESpnIGbDXgDruBbJIITCV4mrTFNsI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

### It is a bug, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/72798634)

The behavior is well known and is already been worked on.

I recommend you to give it a "star" to increase visibility and hopefully speed up the process.

In the meantime, the only workaround is either  not to be signed in with multiple accounts simultaneously or to use incognito mode.

Comment: I figured it out and that's a great pity for a giant company